# Retrying Laravel PHP script with database transaction for 10 seconds

Tags: php, laravel, transactions

I am using Laravel 4.2 I have a huge `try/catch` block for running database transactions. With multiple types of exceptions.

```
$startTime = 0;
try {

DB::beginTransaction();
//code

DB::commit();

}catch(Exception1 $e){

DB::rollBack();
//so something with this, save in db and throw new Exception
if($startTime < 10) retry the whole process

}catch(Exception2 $e){

DB::rollBack();
//so something with this, save in db and throw new Exception
if($startTime < 10) retry the whole process

}catch(Exception $e){

DB::rollBack();
//so something with this, save in db and throw new Exception
if($startTime < 10) retry the whole process
}
```

I want the whole process to retry for 10 seconds. On every fail I need to rollback the changes and try again.

How can I do this properly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap the entire code in "try" into a function that performs the transaction/rollback, and run the function as long as it returns false and it started running less than 10s ago. Typing out of my head, maybe I missed something but I hope you get the picture:

```
function doIt() {
  try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    /**
     * whatever
     */

    DB::commit();

    return true;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
    /**
     * do something more if you need
     */

    return false;
  }
}

$start = time();
do {
  $IdidIt = doIt();
} while(!$IdidIt && (time() - $start <= 10));
```

UPDATE, according to the comment:

```
function tryFor10Seconds(Closure $closure) {

  $runTheClosure = function ($closure) {
    try {
      DB::beginTransaction();

      $closure();

      DB::commit();

      return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      DB::rollBack();

      // handle the exception if needed, log it or whatever

      return false;
    }
  };

  $start = time();
  do {
    $result = $runTheClosure($closure);
  } while(!$result && (time() - $start <= 10));

  return $result;
}
```

So, basically you'd call this like:

```
$success = tryFor10Seconds(function() use ($model1, $model2, $whatever) {
  $model1->save();
  $model2->save();
  $whatever->doSomethingWithDB();
});

if (!$success) {
  // :(
}
```

Comment: That looks good. The thing is that I want to integrated this in other parts of the project. A colleague told me that I should use a closure. So, do you think it will work in getting the `doIt()` method into a closure? That means that every time  want to use this logic of trying for 10 seconds and rolling back I'll have to implement the same logic.

Comment: @RobertGabriel Check the updated answer, would something like that do the work? Basically, you'd write the body of the closure as if it were supposed to be between `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` (or in `DB::transaction()`'s closure), but this way it would be retried for 10 seconds as long as commit() doesn't succeed and 'true' is returned after it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me a lot!